# How can I resolve this error after updating serverless.yml to use new variablesResolutionMode for SSM params?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am trying to resolve the following deprecation warning:

`Serverless: Deprecation warning: Syntax for referencing SSM parameters was upgraded with automatic type detection and there's no need to add "~true" or "~split" postfixes to variable references. Drop those postfixes and set "variablesResolutionMode: 20210326" in your service config to adapt to a new behavior. Starting with next major release, this will be communicated with a thrown error.`

I have removed the `~true` postfix and set the `variablesResolutionMode` to `20210326`. Upon doing so, I get the following error from AWS:

`User: arn:aws:iam::500345361576:user/sls is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:*********:500345361576:*`

I have double checked that this IAM user has the requisite permissions and this all works fine if I revert my changes (to not use the new `variablesResolutionMode`).

Any ideas on how to resolve this?